# Selective display of combo options

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a database for Human Resources in Access. This database primarily keeps track of candidates that apply for job positions in the company and they also keep track of job postings these candidates applied from. I have established a one to many relationship between job postings and candidate tables so that each candidate is linked with specific job posting. On Candidate Details form, job posting can be selected from a combo box.

Since I expect there will be a lot of job postings, I have also included an "Open" and "Closed" status for each job posting so that I could limit options in the combo box for new candidates so that only active postings are shown. The problem is that when I open profiles for old candidates that have applied through closed job postings, their job posting info does not show since combo box is limited to only open job postings.

Is there a logical way to present this info in a combo box, so that for new candidates only open job positions would be displayed while when I open postings for already entered candidates, they would still show the job posting they applied for even if it was closed in the meantime? I hope my post makes sense.

Comment: This is called cascading or conditional combobox. Requires VBA code. Common topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think cascading combobox would do the trick in my case since I don't have a second combo box however I found a workaround by placing conditional rowsource for both scenarios, if record  contains job posting info then it should display all job postings (open and closed) in the combo box and when new record has no job posting info then only display open postings.

Comment: That is a cascading/conditional combobox. The combobox RowSource is conditional on some value in another field, doesn't have to be another combobox. Change value in that field and the combobox RowSource changes. Glad you got it working.